# implement custom pickling code in using ORTools

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, or-tools

I am using multiprocessing and I know the pickle module implements binary protocols for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure.

And also I know which types of data can be pickled, something like Integer,List,Set and ....

But if I want to use something else data which is not pick_able , what I should to do?

More precisely, I want to use multiprocessing to make parallel the creating constraint in ORTools. blow is my code:

```
manager = Manager()
constraints = manager.list(range(16))

def constraint_saz():
    "constraint's condition"

# Create the constraints        
for i in range(len(data)):
    constraints[i] = solver.Constraint(1,1)
    p = Process(target=constraint_saz, args=(constraints,i))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

But i got this error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle SwigPyObject objects
```

what I should to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is feasible as the python is just a light wrapper around C++ object.
Now, the linear solver and the CP-SAT solver supports storing the model in a protobuf object, which can be serialized.

It does raise some issues because when you create your model, you create variables which are linked to your model. After serialization, you do not have these variables available. So querying the solution of the solve() is complex.